# android Fragments and switching tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am using Fragments and a TabHost for the first time and am having some trouble having a fragment in one tab lead to a fragment in another tab. Specifically, tab1 shows Fragment A initially, however the user can select something within that fragment and it will replace it with Fragment B still under tab1. This works fine and the backstack gives a nice user experience.

However, under tab2 I have fragment C and I'd like the user to be able to click something in fragment C and get navigated back to tab1 showing fragment B (even if the user had never gone from A to B in the first place). Ideally, I'd also like the backstack to operate as one would expect in terms of the back button should take the user back to tab2 and fragment C, although that is less important.

Is there a standard way to implement this, or am I stuck hacking something together?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can goto Tab1 and show a fragment B. But I am not very sure if you can manage the backstack with fragment A if the user had never gone from A to B.